# Starting alarm to call IntentService at boot time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to set an alarm at boot time, and have it call an IntentService periodically via the AlarmManager. The AlarmReceiver is never triggered, not sure why.

BootReceiver:

```
package com.company.android;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.text.format.Time;

public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();

        Log.e("#######################COMM", "Booting up " + now.toString());

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("com.company.android.AlarmReceiver");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5, pi);

        Log.e("#######################COMM", "Booted up " + now.toString());
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
package com.company.android;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by mlaino on 7/8/13.
 */
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("COMM", "Pre");


        Intent i = new Intent("com.company.android.PollingService");
        context.startService(i);

        Log.d("COMM","Pos");

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.company.android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0-SNAPSHOT">
    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
      <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.company.android.AlarmReceiver" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

      <activity android:name=".CommunicationsManagerActivity">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <service android:name=".PollingService" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.company.android.PollingService" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
  </application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>
```

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"`, as you are saying that whatever is *calling* your receiver must hold that permission, which may or may not be the case.

Then, be sure to run one of your activities before rebooting, as manifest-registered `BraodcastReceivers` will not work until something explicitly runs one of your components, typically accomplished by the user launching an activity.

Comment: Ok, so the only way to register a broadcast receiver to receive alarms, and then call my IntentService is to run an activity first? No other way? (Due to ignorance, I tried to register AlarmReceiver at boot in the BootBroadcastReceiver, and got a runtime exception). The permission is set on that receiver so it can receive the booted up message :)

Comment: @SoManyGoblins: "No other way?" -- correct. This is to prevent drive-by malware. You can read more about this at http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html and http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: Ok! thank you very much for the clarification, and reading material :)

Comment: Stupid question, being able to open activities during boot couldn't result in malware?

Comment: @SoManyGoblins: You can't open activities during boot. The only thing that can get control via `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` is a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: I meant from the broadcastreceiver to open an activity via intent.

Comment: @SoManyGoblins: The `BroadcastReceiver` will never run, unless the user launched an activity or something else manually ran one of your components. It does not matter whether that `BroadcastReceiver` will start an activity, schedule an alarm, or play the opening measures of "The William Tell Overture" -- it just simply will not run until the app is moved out of the "stopped" state, as described in the documentation I linked to.